# Read n lines from hadoop file which contains part files

Tags: java, hdfs

I am trying to read n lines from hadoop file using FSDataInputStream. When I try to give a path which is dir containing part files. It says Path is not a file. Below is my attempt to read.

Below code works file when I specifically give part file path

````
            FSDataInputStream fsDataInputStream = distributedFileSystem.open(path);
            BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(fsDataInputStream));
            String line;
            while ((line = bufferedReader.readLine()) != null) {
                if (lines.size() < numOfLines)
                 lines.add(line);
                else
                    break;
            }
            bufferedReader.close();```
````

Comment: Can you share the error trace?

Comment: java.io.FileNotFoundException: Path is not a file: /path/to/hadoop/file
 at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.INodeFile.valueOf(INodeFile.java:75)
 at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.INodeFile.valueOf(INodeFile.java:61)
 at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.FSNamesystem.getBlockLocationsInt(FSNamesystem.java:1828)
 at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.FSNamesystem.getBlockLocations(FSNamesystem.java:1799)
 at